# How can I select the folder with the highest number in a drop down list item box using pywinauto?

Tags: python, list, sorting, pywinauto

Following is my code:

```
tool_window2.child_window(auto_id="0", control_type="ListItem").click_input()
```

Right now it always select the first folder because it is the latest by date.

I want to automate the program so it will always select the folder with the highest number(i.e in this case I want folder "244" to be selected)

How do I make this in python using pywinauto? Here is the issue I'm facing:
 [image: link]

Comment: `tool_window2.child_window(title="244", control_type="ListItem").click_input()` ?

Comment: Thank Vasily! However, if somebody would select an older folder like for example 242, then it would go to the top of the list since it was the latest modified. These folders will changed dynamically daily so the structure will never be the same. Next week the folders could be around 260 for example. I just want the program to always select the folder with the highest number. Maybe  something like if the value contained in  auto_id =0 is greater than all the folders, then always select auto id =0 value. However I am not sure how to do this in code. Still learning python coding. thanks!